# Filtering list of elements based on a model @property in a ViewSet - Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Below is a data structure that can be accessible trough an endpoint built with *Django Rest Framework*:

```
"sites": [{
    "id": 1,
    "configs": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "subconfigs": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "subconfig_1",
                    "macro_subconfigs": [1, 2]
                    "flag": true
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "name": "subconfig_2",
                    "macro_subconfigs": [1]
                    "flag": false
                },
                {
                    "id": 3,
                    "name": "subconfig_3",
                    "macro_subconfigs": [2]
                    "flag": false
                },
            ],
            "macro_subconfigs": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "flag": true,
                    "subconfigs": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "name": "subconfig_1",
                            "macro_subconfigs": [1, 2]
                            "flag": true
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 2,
                            "name": "subconfig_2",
                            "macro_subconfigs": [1]
                            "flag": false
                        },
                    ],
                    "name": "macro_subconfig_1"
                },
                {
                    "id": 2,
                    "flag": false,
                    "subconfigs": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "name": "subconfig_1",
                            "macro_subconfigs": [1, 2]
                            "flag": true
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 3,
                            "name": "subconfig_3",
                            "macro_subconfigs": [2]
                            "flag": false
                        },
                    ],
                    "name": "macro_subconfig_2"
                },
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

My models are the followings:

**Config**

```
class Config(TimeStampedModel):
    site = models.ForeignKey("site.Site", related_name="configs")
    @property
    def macro_subconfigs(self):
        try:
            return MacroSubConfig.objects.filter(subconfigs__config__pk=self.pk).distinct()
        except MacroSubConfig.DoesNotExist:
            return tuple()
```

**SubConfig**

```
class SubConfig(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    config = models.ForeignKey(
        "Config", related_name="subconfigs", on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    flag = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

**MacroSubConfig**

```
class MacroSubConfig(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subconfigs = models.ManyToManyField(SubConfig, related_name="macro_subconfigs")
    flag = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

And my serializers:

```
class SiteConfigSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    configs = ConfigSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Site
        fields = ("name", "configs")

class SubConfigSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SubConfig
        fields = ("name")

class ConfigSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    subconfigs = SubConfigSerializer(many=True)
    macro_subconfigs = MacroSubConfigSerializer(many=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Config
        fields = ("name", "subconfigs", "macro_subconfigs")

class MacroSubConfigSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    subconfigs = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True, queryset=SubConfig.objects.all()
    )
    class Meta:
        model = MacroSubConfig
        fields = ["subconfigs", "name"]
```

In my `SiteViewSet`, I would like to filter `macro_subconfigs` in the macro_subconfigs's list which have `flag: true`. I already managed to do the same for `subconfigs` in the subconfigs's list.

The expected result is the following:

```
"sites": [{
    "id": 1,
    "configs": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "subconfigs": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "name": "subconfig_1",
                    "macro_subconfigs": [1, 2]
                    "flag": true
                }
            ],
            "macro_subconfigs": [
                {
                    "id": 1,
                    "flag": true,
                    "subconfigs": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "name": "subconfig_1",
                            "macro_subconfigs": [1, 2]
                            "flag": true
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 2,
                            "name": "subconfig_2",
                            "macro_subconfigs": [1]
                            "flag": false
                        },
                    ],
                    "name": "macro_subconfig_1"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}]
```

How do you filter elements from a list in the Config object, in the `SiteViewSet`?

Feel free to ask me more precisions if needed. Thanks

---

**More infos**

What I have tried in my ViewSet

```
class SiteConfigViewSet(PublicViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.SiteConfigSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        subconfigs =  Process.objects.filter(flag=True)
        macro_subconfigs =  MacroProcess.objects.filter(flag=True)
        return permissions.get_allowed_sites(self.request).prefetch_related(
            Prefetch("configs__subconfigs", queryset=subconfigs),
            Prefetch("configs__subconfigs__macro_subconfigs", queryset=macro_subconfigs),
    )
```

Comment: I don't understand your expected result, the `macro_subconfig` object has `flag` set to `true` but you say you want those with `flag` set to `false`.

Comment: Where's the code for your `SiteViewSet`? What have you tried?

Comment: @dirkgroten Small mistake, I want to keep in my list all `macro_subconfig` which have `flag`set to `true`

Comment: @dirkgroten I updated the post with the ViewSet

Comment: `prefetch_related` only helps reducing the number of queries to the db. Your `Serializers` actually determine which objects are serialized. You should either edit current serializers’ QuerySets or if you need both cases, subclass them and use the subclasses serializer in your viewset. Or make them configurable and set an attribute when initializing the serializer (you’ll have to change your viewset to override `get_serializer()`)